# Horizontal Scrollable GridView

Tags: android, gridview, imagebutton, scrollable

[As shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC1ZX.png),

[I want to create a Grid View / View with Grid of Levels that is Horizontally Scrollable.

Levels are stored in DB. So, the grid needs to be populated dynamically. The grid can contain ImageButtons of 9 Levels at a time. To show the next 9 levels, the view should be horizontally scrollabe.

Any help will be highly appreciated]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ViewPager` and `Fragment` API.